# How to use Super-L instead of Alt in XFCE for resizing/moving windows?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, window-manager

In XFCE, when holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then clicking anywhere in a window with the left button will move that window (as if by dragging the title bar), or resize the windows when clicking and dragging with the right button.

I like this feature very much, and I'm used to it, since forever. But I've always had it bound to <kbd>Super-L</kbd>(left "Windows"-Key).

How do I change the behavior of <kbd>Alt</kbd> for <kbd>Super-L</kbd>? I was looking at *XFCE Settings Manager* but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the Settings Manager choose *Window Manager Tweaks*, then on the third tab, *Accessibility* you will find the control *Key used to grab and move windows*:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to exist in xfce4, and I was unable to find an equivalent.

Comment: @JimStewart I just had that problem in xubuntu 17.10 and the post above works fine for me

Comment: How to change it to `Right Alt` ?  (it works only with Left Alt for me)

Answer (score 3):

As @jim-stewart wrote in his note, the "Window Manager Tweaks" does not seem to be installed (in some cases / by default) in the current xfce.

I could set the *Window* key for moving the windows by

- going into "Settings > Settings Editor",
- choose the "xfwm4" channel and
- set `easy_click` to `Super" (it's`Alt` by default).

Comment: Hmm, Window Manager Tweaks ist still in my version. (4.12)

Comment: I was installing an Italian Xfce on Debian stable and I could not find it. I might be missing some packages. Maybe, it's just not installed by default... On the other side, the "Settings Editor" should always be installed.